# How To Do onRendered Template like on Meteor React's Component

Tags: meteor, reactjs

I would like to show canvas on template rendered using React Component.
We know that in Blaze's Style we could perform that with something like,

```
Template.test.onRendered = function(){
    // draw the canvas
}
```

How do we call canvas onRendered if using component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you're looking for `componentDidMount()`.  The Meteor Chef has a few good blog posts on his blog.  Here's a link to one of his first [React walkthroughs](https://themeteorchef.com/recipes/getting-started-with-react/).

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out man, you are correct,
https://themeteorchef.com/blog/react-vs-blaze/#tmc-react-methods-vs-blaze-methods

Comment: but what exactly we should put on componentDidMount method?
please enlighten me